# Is it possible to use two keyboards simultaneously while designating their outputs to two different applications?

Tags: linux

Is it possible on MAC OS x or linux, to have two sets of keyboard and mouse working simultaneously and independently on one computer?

Comment: Yes but it's usually no out of the box setup. Having independent hardware is probably going to be favorable. Why do you have that specific need?

Comment: It's because we are going to join in a competition where we are allowed to possess only one laptop and one external keyboard, and I thought it could bring us unexpected advantage from being able to use our resources more efficiently. I do feel a little shameful having this in mind, but still I'm interested in making this possible, and I'm willing to spend some time on implementing it if necessary.

Comment: As you would still only have a single screen (which one person would pretty much need to be directly in front of) it would be hard for the other person to actually see anything. In addition you wouldn't be able to use e.g. independent virtual desktops for each set of input devices as you would only have a single output. What you're looking for is a [multi-seat setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration#GNU.2FLinux). There are solutions available but they usually assume that each person has his own display as well (from what I know).

Comment: I have looked up about multi-seat setups, while most documents seem to be either incomplete or too brief, it does seem very uncommon to have it implemented on a single monitor. However, I don't mind if one of us would be unable to see the screen as we are very experienced typists. Do you mind showing some more hints, links, or alternatives that could still achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very brief summary how keyboard input works under Linux:

Keyboard events from the lower hardware layers are passed to the Linux kernel input layer, and made available on `/dev/input/eventX` device nodes. The X server reads these events, and translates them into X keyboard events, which are passed to graphical applications running under X.

So you can

- assign the two keyboards to different X servers
- assign the two keyboards to different "seats", which usually include keyboard/mouse/display each, and may or may not use different X servers
- decouple one keyboard from the "core keyboard" with `xinput`, and have an application that understands the Xinput extension process the X keyboard events directly (most applications can't do that).
- decouple the X server from the `/dev/input/eventX` node, with `xinput`, configuration, or by "grabbing" the device for exclusive access (try `evtest --grab`), and then have the application somehow process the input-level events directly (which most applications can't).

In the end, it heavily depends on the application that wants to use the "independent" keyboard. Setting up two X servers, one of them "nested" in some way (`Xpra`, `Xephyr` etc.), may be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible if you are running one or more of your OS(s) on **VMs**. Just have to make some tweaks in input settings of VitualBox or VMPlayer or whatever the **Hypervisor** you are using.